# How hadoop can help user data tracking?

Tags: logging, hadoop, mapreduce

I am wondering how hadoop can help user data tracking. For example, I have an e-Commerce application and I want to record every single activity performed by the customer, such as view item, add to cart or purchase item. Is there an example or best practices regarding logging of events using hadoop. The reason why I want to use hadoop is because of its High Availability and scale-ability, also the logged data will grow from GBs to TBs. Or am I wrong? becuase the logging should be independent of hadoop and later analytics on logged data can be done with hadoop?

is Hadoop only about MapReduce? if I can use hadoop for logging or tracking of activities, then what is the Map and what would be the Reduce functions?

Could anyone please shed light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is all about processing the large data and  producing the important statistics with `mapreduce` programs.  In your case you can use the `mapreduce` programs to analyse your logs to see that which of your online products are  viewed most stuffs like that

> is Hadoop only about MapReduce?

No it is about larger data processing.

```
if I can use hadoop for logging or tracking of activities,
```

you can't use hadoop for server logging it is the task of your app server.

> then what is the Map and what would be the Reduce functions?

Map and Reduce are the patterns followed by Hadoop to process the data

Hope that hepls.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an interesting material to study. I have executed the experiment. It works pretty well!

http://www.lopakalogic.com/articles/hadoop-articles/log-files-flume-hive/

Also

https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/flume_and_hive_for_log